# Как изменить описание текстового канала discord.py

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Как изменить тему текстового канала в `discord.py`?

[image: тема канала]

Вроде бы банальный вопрос, но ответа в интернете и документации я не нашёл.

Answer (score 1):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", help_command=None)
@client.command(name="test")
async def test(ctx):
    channelId = 1234567890
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, id=channelId)
    await channel.edit(topic="new topic name")

client.run("token")
```

Данный фрагмент кода при отправке команды */test* меняет описание канала с id - 1234567890 на "new topic name"

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!change_topic'):
        channel = message.channel
        topic = 'New topic'
        await channel.edit(topic=topic)
        await message.channel.send('Topic changed!')
        
client.run('TOKEN')
```

Я также воспользовался chatGPT для данного вопроса и вот, что он выдал
По команде *!change_topic* бот меняет тему канала в котором была прописана команда на 'New topic', попутно извещая о смене темы

Comment: Оно работает как то странно, то работает, то просто игнорит без ошибок

Comment: Метод можно использовать примерно раз в 10 минут. Это ограничение не обойти

Comment: Жаль. Очень жаль